# Proof of Khintchine's inequality on $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I'm trying to understand [this proof](https://lemmameringue.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/khintchines-inequality) of Khintchine's inequality for the complex case ($a_n\in\mathbb{C}$). The author claims that the complex case follows from the real case by taking absolute values where appropriate, but I don't see where to place those absolut values, even after filling in the details of the proof:

**Proof (for $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$):** Let $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n$ be some i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb P(\epsilon_k=\pm1)=\frac12$ and let $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ (w.l.o.g. $\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2=1$). For every $\lambda>0$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E(\exp(\lambda\epsilon_ka_k))
&=\sum_{j=\pm1}\exp(j\lambda a_k)\cdot\overbrace{\mathbb P(\epsilon_k=j)}^{=1/2}
=\cosh(\lambda a_k)
=\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\frac{(\lambda a_k)^{2\ell}}{(2\ell)!} \\
&\leq\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\frac{(\lambda^2a_k^2)^\ell}{2^\ell\cdot\ell!}
=\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\frac{(\lambda^2a_k^2\,/\,2)^\ell}{\ell!}
=\exp(\lambda^2a_k^2\,/\,2),
\end{align*}
$$
which gives us
$$
\mathbb E\bigg(\exp\bigg(\lambda\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon_ka_k\bigg)\bigg)
=\prod_{k=1}^n\mathbb E(\exp(\lambda\epsilon_ka_k))
\leq\prod_{k=1}^n\exp(\lambda^2a_k^2\,/\,2)
=\exp\bigg(\frac{\lambda^2}2\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\bigg)
=\exp(\lambda^2\,/\,2),
$$
and thus
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\bigg(\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon_ka_k\bigg|\geq\lambda\bigg)
&=2\mathbb P\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon_ka_k\geq\lambda\bigg)
=2\mathbb P\bigg(\exp\bigg(\lambda\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon_ka_k\bigg)\geq\exp(\lambda^2)\bigg) \\
&\overset{(*)}\leq\frac2{\exp(\lambda^2)}\mathbb E\bigg(\exp\bigg(\lambda\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon_ka_k\bigg)\bigg)
\leq\frac2{\exp(\lambda^2)}\exp(\lambda^2\,/\,2)
=\exp(-\lambda^2\,/\,2),
\end{align*}
$$
where $(*)$ uses the fact that for every $\alpha>0$ and every real or complex (integrable) random variable $X$ we have
$$
\mathbb P(|X|\geq\alpha)
=\mathbb E\Big(1\cdot1_{\big\{\frac{|X|}\alpha\geq1\big\}}\Big)
\leq\mathbb E\Big(\frac{|X|}\alpha\cdot1_{\big\{\frac{|X|}\alpha\geq1\big\}}\Big)
\leq\mathbb E\Big(\frac{|X|}\alpha\Big)
=\frac1\alpha\mathbb E|X|.
$$
[... The rest of the proof is irrelevant for my question ...] $\blacksquare$

---

Now, **my question** is where do I have to put absolut values in the inequalities above to prove the complex case? In order for the first block to make sense in $\mathbb{C}$ we need to replace $(\lambda a_k)^{2\ell}$ with $|\lambda a_k|^{2\ell}$. We have
$$
|\mathbb E(\exp(\lambda\epsilon_ka_k))|
=|\cosh(\lambda a_k)|
\leq\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\frac{|\lambda a_k|^{2\ell}}{(2\ell)!}
\leq\cdots\leq\exp(\lambda^2|a_k|^2\,/\,2),
$$
which implies
$$
\bigg|\mathbb E\bigg(\exp\bigg(\lambda\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon_ka_k\bigg)\bigg)\bigg|
=\prod_{k=1}^n|\mathbb E(\exp(\lambda\epsilon_ka_k))|
\leq\cdots\leq\exp\bigg(\frac{\lambda^2}2\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^2\bigg)
=\exp(\lambda^2\,/\,2).
$$
But this last result leads me nowhere. I don't see how to translate the third block into complex numbers such that I can make use of the last result.

Comment: I don’t get the linked proof. It looks like it has its inequality the wrong way around in Jensen’s inequality, which would be $\mathbb{E}\exp(X) \geq \exp(\mathbb{E}X)$, not $\leq$.

Comment: Well, maybe you understand my more-fleshed-out part of the proof, which doesn't require the knowledge of the article (I just linked to it as a source for the claim that the complex case should be as easy as the real case)

Comment: I see it now, thanks.